# Correct format to add data to web service

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I am trying to send data to this [web service](http://www.syncro-it.co.uk/service/server.php?wsdl).

With the following code I have how can I adjust what I have to send the `CorrelationId` in C#?

```
www.SyncroWebService ws = new www.SyncroWebService();

ws.addNewProduct(new www.AddProductRequest(){
   Products = new www.Product[]
   {
      new www.Product() { categoryName = "Cat_Rory", departmentName = "Dept_Rory", productName = "Product_Rory", productPrice = 100, productQty = 1000},
      new www.Product() { categoryName = "Cat_Test", departmentName = "Dept_Test", productName = "Product_Test", productPrice = 100, productQty = 1000 }
   }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
ws.addNewProduct(new www.AddProductRequest {
   CorrelationId = "id here",
   Products = ...
```